# Can't Fix Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have this very annoying type mismatch error occuring in my if statement that i just can not seem to fix. Someone's help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    lrIPA = Sheets("IPA").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    A = 2
    Do
        'this is where my error is happening!****
        If Worksheets("IPA").Cells(A, 4).Value - Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8").Value > Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I6").Value Then
            B = 3
            SL = False
            Do
                If Cells(B, 2).Value = Sheets("IPA").Cells(A, 2).Value Then
                    If Sheets("IPA").Cells(A, 5).Value = "" Then
                        Cells(B, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Sheets("IPA").Cells(A, 4).Value - Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8"), -5)
                        'this just stores the unrounded CAD values
                        Cells(B, 100).Value = Sheets("IPA").Cells(A, 4).Value - Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8")
                    ElseIf Sheets("IPA").Cells(A, 5).Value = "USD" Then
                        Cells(B, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Sheets("IPA").Cells(A, 4).Value - Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8"), -5)
                    End If
                    SL = True
                End If
                B = B + 1
            Loop Until SL = True Or B > lrIA
        End If
        A = A + 1
    Loop Until A > lrIPA
```

Comment: Care to let us know which line it's on?

Comment: the line right below where i wrote " 'this is where my error is happening!**** " @DougGlancy

Comment: Yikes. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Orphid, I'm reading too fast. `A` is a variable.

Comment: What are the values in those cells?

Comment: they're large $ amounts, so they'd be something like 500,000 - 100,000 > 300,000

Comment: where cell I8 is 100,000 and cell I6 is 300,000

Comment: As per my comment, if they are currency types, try using CCur?

Comment: I have tried clng, cdl, cint, ccur.. everthing still gives type mismatch @Orphid

Comment: @DougGlancy do you have any suggestions??

Comment: Does the comparison work correctly if you do it in the worksheet itself? Are some of the numbers actually text?

Comment: I created a workbook with sheets "IPA" and "Master Sheet". I put the values 100 in d2, IPA, 10 in i6, Master Sheet, and 25 in i8, master sheet. I I set them all to currency values, and broke down the if statement to see where the problem occurred. Once it was broken-down, however, the problem just stopped occurring.

Comment: yeah it works perfectly fine if i do it directly on the sheet. it also works if i dont have it subtract the 100,000 found in cell I8.. ie

 If Worksheets("IPA").Cells(A, 4).Value > Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I6").Value Then

 works perfectly fine

Comment: In my test, if I set IPA d2 to 5 and Master Sheet I6 to 10, I don't have any problems with the code in my edited answer.

Comment: the code will run now with what you've given me, but its not running correctly.. it is saying that some values arent actually greater that i8 = 300,000 so it itsn't pulling those values.. i honestly don't see how it cannot do this simple calculation. I am so confused as to what is going on with my code

Comment: Can you tell me what values I should put in my workbook to reproduce your error?

Comment: if we let A =39, then Sheets("IPA").Cells(A, 4).Value has value 26,934,089.60 and the i8 is 100000 and i6 is 300000, i need it to give me the value 26,800,000.. but instead it is pulling nothing. it will pull 26,934,089.60 if i remove - Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8").Value from the if statement. If i break the equation up, it will run the code but will return 0 everywhere (where clearly 26,800,000 s much larger than 300,000).. i just dont get why the if statement wont take the simple expression @Orphid

Comment: What do you mean by "give you the value"? When I put the values you describe into the workbook and run my code, the "true" statement is printed. When I evaluate `?Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Sheets("IPA").cells(39, 4).Value - Sheets("Master Sheet").range("I8"), -5)` in the immediate window, I get 26,800,000. Is it that E3 is not assigned this value?

Comment: In Cells(151,6) on master sheet  i should be getting the value 26,800,000.. instead I am getting blank cells. I understand that the code you provided me with would privde "true" but i need it to evaluate the expresion Cells(B, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Sheets("IPA").Cells(A, 4).Value - Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8"), -5)

Comment: @Orphid have you ever encountered this type of issue before

Comment: You could try using`Value2` instead of Value. It treats values formatted as currency differently. Should have thought of this sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that VBA is recognizing the contents of the cells as numbers, by explicitly casting them to integers or longs, as per their size. To do this would use:

```
If cint(Worksheets("IPA").Cells("A", 4).Value) - cint(Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8").Value) > cint(Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I6").Value) Then
```

For longer numbers, replace cint with clng. If they are floats, use CDbl, etc.

<s>You should also use `cells("A", 4)`, unless A is a variable you have assigned elsewhere as a string.</s>

EDIT:

Ok, so I tried it out in a very simple way. I broke down the long conditional statement, and it worked:

```
Sub tst()


Dim d2 As Currency, i8 As Currency, i6 As Currency

d2 = CCur(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IPA").Cells(2, 4).Value)
i8 = CCur(Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8").Value)
i6 = CCur(Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I6").Value)
If d2 - i8 > i6 Then
    Debug.Print "true"
End If

End Sub
```

CInt will also work with cells with currency types, but mind for overflow.

Comment: Try using CCur instead

Answer (score 0):

I've got a couple of suggestions to make that should make it easier to trouble-shoot the problem.

1. In this line of code `Loop Until SL = True Or B > lrIA` is there a typo? Should that last variable be `lrIPA`? It is a good idea to use brackets when writing this kind of line because it is much easier to read. `Loop Until (SL = True) Or (B > lrIPA)`
2. Several times you are using the `Cells` method (e.g. `If Cells(B, 2).Value = ...`) but without specifying the worksheet. This can be dangerous if you end up changing the `ActiveSheet`.
3. If you find you are using the same worksheets many times in code, then using a worksheet variable often makes the code easier to read. For example,

> If Worksheets("IPA").Cells(A, 4).Value - Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8").Value > Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I6").Value Then

Can get changed to:

```
Dim ipaSheet As Worksheet
Dim masterSheet As Worksheet

Set ipaSheet = Worksheets("IPA")
Set masterSheet = Worksheets("Master Sheet")

If ipaSheet.Cells(A, 4).Value - masterSheet.Range("I8").Value > masterSheet.Range("I6").Value Then
```

4. You use the values from `Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I6").Value` and `Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("I8").Value` a lot. It will be easier to store those values in a variable and then just use the variable. If the contents in the cells are likely to change during the macro, then use a range variable instead.
5. Storing your values in variables also lets you check the values in the IDE window by hovering the mouse over the variable or using the Locals window. If there is a problem with your data (e.g. there is text but it should be a number) this should also get picked up when storing the value into the variable.

Putting all these points together and applying them to your code block, it becomes:

```
Dim lrIPA As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim SL As Boolean

Dim i8Value As Currency ' Use a more meaningful name
Dim i6Value As Currency ' Use a more meaningful name
Dim ipaValue As Currency ' Use a more meaningful name
Dim roundedValue As Currency ' Use a more meaningful name

Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
Dim ipaSheet As Worksheet

Set ipaSheet = Worksheets("IPA")
Set masterSheet = Worksheets("Master Sheet")

lrIPA = ipaSheet.Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

i8Value = CCur(masterSheet.Range("I8").Value)
i6Value = CCur(masterSheet.Range("I6").Value)

A = 2
Do
    ipaValue = CCur(ipaSheet.Cells(RowIndex:=A, ColumnIndex:=4).Value)
    'this is where my error is happening!****
    If (ipaValue - i8Value) > i6Value Then
        B = 3
        SL = False
        Do
            If masterSheet.Cells(B, 2).Value = ipaSheet.Cells(A, 2).Value Then
                roundedValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(ipaValue - i8Value, -5)
                If ipaSheet.Cells(A, 5).Value = "" Then
                    masterSheet.Cells(B, 5).Value = roundedValue
                    'this just stores the unrounded CAD values
                    masterSheet.Cells(B, 100).Value = ipaValue - i8Value
                ElseIf ipaSheet.Cells(A, 5).Value = "USD" Then
                    masterSheet.Cells(B, 6).Value = roundedValue
                End If
                SL = True ' Maybe use "Exit Do" instead to quit the loop?
            End If
            B = B + 1
        Loop Until (SL = True) Or (B > lrIPA)
    Else
    End If
    A = A + 1
Loop Until A > lrIPA
```

If you step through this code using F8 it should be easy to check the value of the variables at each stage.

Comment: Thank you for your code! I ended up using both your advice and @Orphid `s advice.. however I still ended up having the same annoying mistamtch error. What ended up being the solution (which really frustrates me because i should have done this from the beginning) was that all I needed to add was On Error Resume Next line.. the second i put this in, it ran beautifully. I appreciate all the help you guys gave me! Thanks :)

Comment: The problem with `On Error Resume Next` in this scenario is that you are just hiding the underlying problem. And you might not be getting accurate results every time. Want to post the revised code as a new post for us to take a look?